# Conflict with ajax while using with Jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax

hi i am using jquery tab in my page. but while using update pannel both tab will appear in same page. this occures after a post back.. is any problem is there for using jquery and update pannel together? How can i overcome this?

Comment: It's hard to answer this question in the abstract.  There shouldn't inherently be an incompatibility.  Could you show us the page as it currently is, or at least your code?

Comment: there is no problem using Jquery but please post ur code so that we can help u more.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using the jquery-ui tabs and `<asp:updatePanel>` controls on the same page, and it's not the best setup, but it works. One thing that really got me was that `tabs()` wasn't being called after a partial-postback call to `DataBind()` in one of the inner ASP.NET controls. I worked around it this way, and perhaps this will help you:

```
function refreshTabs() {
    $("#tabs").tabs();
}

function pageLoad () {
    refreshTabs();
}
```

By putting the call to `tabs()` inside ASP.NET's `pageLoad()` function instead of jquery's `$()` function, it's called after every postback, even if only a partial postback was triggered.

Hope this helps!